# VSTS Build error, Cannot import the key file

Tags: uwp, azure-pipelines

I'm using the default Universal Windows Build definition on VSTS (visualstudio.com). The Build Solution step is erroring on the certificate. Here is the error:

> Error APPX0105: Cannot import the key file 'xxx.xxx.UwpApp_TemporaryKey.pfx'. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate store.

I'm not sure how to resolve in VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

I found these posts which solved the issue. Not sure why MS doesn't offer an easier way to solve this.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1da71626-10e1-49d9-bdcb-fc1e9b3b6465/pfx-build-error-for-uwp-app?forum=TFService

[VisualStudio.com can't load the temporary UWP certificate during builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841222/visualstudio-com-cant-load-the-temporary-uwp-certificate-during-builds)